# What type of games need to include GDF file?

Tags: windows-store-apps

I am submitting a "Tic-Tac-Toe" player app to Windows 8 Store. Do I need to include Game Definition File ? Will they certify my app even if I don't include one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be really careful with certification. Include all possible certificates and select only countries that accept these certificates. Yes, you should include GDF file. Again, you should include only certificates that you have to the GDF file. I lost more than a week while tried to submit right age raiting values for a simply puzzle game.
GDF file is very easy to create.

Comment: any links for how-to create GDF files? what should be the age rating for this game?

Comment: [how to create GDF file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465153.aspx). I think that you can set 3+, if your game is like tic-tac-toe and you have no erotic backgrounds ;) You can get [PEGI certificate](http://apps.pegi.eu/Games/Submit) and [ESRB](https://autoratingtool.esrb.org/ARTclient/Windows8Metro.aspx?fwLinkID=224194) online.